# How can I execute a click event after a jQuery element has been completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload-event

How can I execute a click event after an element has been completely loaded?

The following code is intended to attach a load event to a ul tag for this purpose, but it doesn't work.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.nav-tabs').on('load', function () {
        // Breakpoint A: Control never gets here
        if (typeof (Storage) === "undefined")
            return;
        $(localStorage.setItem("CanTabId")).click();
    })
    // Breakpoint B: No click event seems to be attached
})
```

In my ignorance of jQuery, I can think of several explanations:

1. The event is never attached. I support of this, I see that the ul does not have a click event at Breakpoint B.  I suppose jQuery might handle events some other way, but it doesn't seem likely.
2. The event is attached, but the load event has already occurred for the ul.
3. Something that jQuery does to the page later has removed the click event.

Note -- This event works:

```
$('.nav-tabs li a').on('click', function () {...))
```

I have not been able to find an answer on SO, or anywhere.

Can someone tell me the right way to do this?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you create JSfiddle for us please. That will make it better, for us to debug :)

Comment: at first: localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom'); after that you can: localStorage.getItem('myCat');

Comment: there are only a select few elements that have a load event ... img, iframe etc. If you are loading with ajax use ajax callback

Comment: The `load` event doesn't bubble. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  If you want to set local storage, you could put it in a `$(document).ready()`, `window.onload' or AJAX `success` (or `done`) function, depending on what's happening on your page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know if the "element loaded" event is still supported or not; but either way you shouldn't actually need it since you're already executing inside of a [document ready event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). This should be sufficient:

```
$(function() {
    // document ready has fired - all your elements should have loaded.
    if (typeof (Storage) === "undefined")
        return;

    $(localStorage.getItem("CanTabId")).click();
})
```

[Here's a fiddle that demonstrates](https://jsfiddle.net/4107Lfup/).

Also a possible bug, you're trying to `setItem` when attaching the `click` event handler - should this be `getItem`?

```
$(localStorage.getItem("CanTabId")).click();
```